# `groupby` column not passed to `apply` function. Possible bug in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

Possible bug in `GroupBy.apply` (pandas 0.25.3):
The following code makes a `groupby` by the `class` column, and the applied function tries to access the `class` column. The code produces a `KeyError: 'class'` exception:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ("bird", "Falconiformes", 389.0),
        ("bird", "Psittaciformes", 24.0),
        ("mammal", "Carnivora", 80.2),
        ("mammal", "Primates", 20),
        ("mammal", "Carnivora", 58),
    ],
    index=["falcon", "parrot", "lion", "monkey", "leopard"],
    columns=("class", "order", "max_speed"),
)

class_to_features = {"bird": ["wings", "feathers", "beak"], "mammal": ["udder"]}


def exec_groupby(df, _temp, c_2_f=None):
    def _helper(df):
        if c_2_f is not None:
            return c_2_f[df["class"].iloc[0]] + _temp # KeyError "class"
        else:
            return "goo" + _temp

    return df.groupby(["class"]).apply(lambda df: _helper(df))

print(exec_groupby(df, "foo"))
print(exec_groupby(df, "foo", class_to_features))
```

However, if I remove the `+ _temp` from the `return` statement it works fine!

```py
def exec_groupby(df, _temp, c_2_f=None):
    def _helper(df):
        if c_2_f is not None:
            return c_2_f[df["class"].iloc[0]] # Works fine! no errors
        else:
            return "goo" + _temp

    return df.groupby(["class"]).apply(lambda df: _helper(df))
```

It seems like a combination of `c_2_f` not being `None` and access the column that causes the exception. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error log reads

```
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
...
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
...
KeyError: 'class'
```

`c_2_f` has keys which are lists, so you can't concatenate it with `str`

```
def exec_groupby(df, _temp, c_2_f=None):
    def _helper(df):
        if c_2_f is not None:
            return c_2_f[df["class"].iloc[0]] + [_temp] # Works fine! no errors
        else:
            return "goo" + _temp

    return df.groupby(["class"]).apply(lambda df: _helper(df))
```

This works fine and gives

```
class
bird      goofoo
mammal    goofoo
dtype: object
class
bird      [wings, feathers, beak, foo]
mammal                    [udder, foo]
dtype: object
```